# Is it possible to set a default method for a class in python?

Tags: python, class, methods

Suppose you have a class in python. We'll call it `C`. And suppose you create an instance of it somewhere in your script, or in interactive mode: `c=C()`

Is is possible to have a "default" method in the class, such that when you reference the instance, that default method gets called?

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def method0(self):
        return 0
    def method1(self):
        return 1
    def ...
        ...
    def default(self):
        return "Nothing to see here, move along"
```

And so on.

Now I create an instance of the class in interactive mode, and reference it:

```
>>> c=C(3,4)
>>> c
<__main__.C object at 0x6ffffe67a50>
>>> print(c)
<__main__.C object at 0x6ffffe67a50>
>>>
```

Is is possible to have a default method that gets called if you reference the object by itself, as shown below?

```
>>> c
'Nothing to see here, move along'
>>> print(c)
Nothing to see here, move along
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is the [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__repr__#object.__repr__) method, which returns the string representation of an instance of the class. You can override the method like this:

```
class C:
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Nothing to see here, move along'
```

so that:

```
>>> c=C()
>>> c
Nothing to see here, move along
>>> print(c)
Nothing to see here, move along
>>>
```

Comment: Nice. I figured python would have something like this.

`__str__` and `__repr__` can only return strings?

What if I want to return a list, or an array, or something else?

Comment: The `__repr__` and the `__str__` methods can only return strings. What is your use case for it to return anything else?

Comment: Not `__repr__` specifically, but the want for being able to call `c(...)` is for functional purposes. If your class has a primary function, it's nice to just be able to "call" the class... all the other methods become support for the primary function. For example scala has the `apply` method, in which `c.apply(arg)` and `c(arg)` is identical.

Answer (score 2):

Any code that you want to run when an object starts should go in `__init__()` and if you want to alter the effect of `print(instance)` you can overwrite the `__repr__()` of the object. Together it would look like:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print(self.__repr__())
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'nothing to see here'

c = C(3, 4)
print(c)
```

Outputting:

```
nothing to see here
nothing to see here
```

Where the first is printed when the class is made by calling `print(self.__repr__())` and the next print comes from `print(c)`